# Selenium cannot click button because there is a div overlay

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to scrap this webpage https://www.tecnocasa.es/venta/piso/barcelona/barcelona/510567.html, the code i use is the following, and i think is correct:

```
options = Options()
options.headless = False
driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options, executable_path=r'geckodriver.exe')
driver.get(url)
# ("Headless Firefox Initialized")
#dins del id= cookie-banner
frame = driver.find_element(by=By.CSS_SELECTOR,value = '[id = "cookie-banner"]')
print(frame)
buttons = frame.find_elements(by=By.TAG_NAME, value='button')
print(buttons)
buttons[0].click()

time.sleep(5)
```

The buttons are found but when i try to click one i have the error  `<button class="btn-default"> is not clickable at point (1138,829) because another element <div id="hide-overlay" class="hide-overlay fade-leave-active fade-leave-to"> obscures it`

How can i disable this overlay and click the button to accept the conditions of the page?

Comment: you can use JavaScript code to remove element from browser, or you can use JavaScript code to click this element, something like `execute_script("arguments[0].click(), buttons[0])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code works without any problem on my computer, try this one

```
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#close').click()
```

If also this will not work, you can try this code which hides the banner. However, you should run it each time that a new page is loaded

```
overlay = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div.cookies-overlay')
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].style.display = 'none';", overlay)
banner = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#cookie-banner')
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].style.display = 'none';", banner)
```